# deduplicating commons-validator - sbt assembly

Tags: scala, maven, sbt

Below is dependency graph of commons-validator

in my build I have

```
"commons-validator" % "commons-validator" % "1.4.1"
```

And below is dependency graph for commons-validator

```
[info]   +-commons-validator:commons-validator:1.4.1
[info]   | +-commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.8.3
[info]   | | +-commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1 (evicted by: 1.2)
[info]   | | +-commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
[info]   | |
[info]   | +-commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1
[info]   | +-commons-digester:commons-digester:1.8.1
[info]   | +-commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
```

When I run sbt assembly to build a standalone jar, I get

```
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:assembly for the full output.
[error] (*:assembly) deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/ali/.ivy2/cache/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/jars/commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar:org/apache/commons/collections/ArrayStack.class
[error] /Users/ali/.ivy2/cache/commons-collections/commons-collections/jars/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:org/apache/commons/collections/ArrayStack.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/ali/.ivy2/cache/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/jars/commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar:org/apache/commons/collections/Buffer.class
[error] /Users/ali/.ivy2/cache/commons-collections/commons-collections/jars/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:org/apache/commons/collections/Buffer.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/ali/.ivy2/cache/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/jars/commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar:org/apache/commons/collections/BufferUnderflowException.class
[error] /Users/ali/.ivy2/cache/commons-collections/commons-collections/jars/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:org/apache/commons/collections/BufferUnderflowException.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/ali/.ivy2/cache/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/jars/commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar:org/apache/commons/collections/FastHashMap$1.class
[error] /Users/ali/.ivy2/cache/commons-collections/commons-collections/jars/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:org/apache/commons/collections/FastHashMap$1.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/ali/.ivy2/cache/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/jars/commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar:org/apache/commons/collections/FastHashMap$CollectionView$CollectionViewIterator.class
[error] /Users/ali/.ivy2/cache/commons-collections/commons-collections/jars/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:org/apache/commons/collections/FastHashMap$CollectionView$CollectionViewIterator.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/ali/.ivy2/cache/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/jars/commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar:org/apache/commons/collections/FastHashMap$CollectionView.class
[error] /Users/ali/.ivy2/cache/commons-collections/commons-collections/jars/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:org/apache/commons/collections/FastHashMap$CollectionView.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/ali/.ivy2/cache/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/jars/commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar:org/apache/commons/collections/FastHashMap$EntrySet.class
[error] /Users/ali/.ivy2/cache/commons-collections/commons-collections/jars/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:org/apache/commons/collections/FastHashMap$EntrySet.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/ali/.ivy2/cache/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/jars/commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar:org/apache/commons/collections/FastHashMap$KeySet.class
[error] /Users/ali/.ivy2/cache/commons-collections/commons-collections/jars/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:org/apache/commons/collections/FastHashMap$KeySet.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/ali/.ivy2/cache/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/jars/commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar:org/apache/commons/collections/FastHashMap$Values.class
[error] /Users/ali/.ivy2/cache/commons-collections/commons-collections/jars/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:org/apache/commons/collections/FastHashMap$Values.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/ali/.ivy2/cache/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/jars/commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar:org/apache/commons/collections/FastHashMap.class
[error] /Users/ali/.ivy2/cache/commons-collections/commons-collections/jars/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:org/apache/commons/collections/FastHashMap.class
```

Any ideas as how to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 4):

Could be useful for others,

```
 ("commons-validator" % "commons-validator" % "1.4.1").exclude("commons-beanutils","commons-beanutils"),
  "commons-beanutils" % "commons-beanutils-bean-collections" % "1.8.3"
```