# sbt-assembly: Merge Errors - Deduplicate

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, sbt-assembly, apache-spark-1.5

I am getting these errors using `sbt assembly`.

I am using Spark which seems to be at the root of this problem.

```
val Spark =  Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion
)
```

Error:

```
[error] 12 errors were encountered during merge
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last coreBackend/*:assembly for the full output.
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last core/*:assembly for the full output.
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last commons/*:assembly for the full output.
[error] (coreBackend/*:assembly) deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Volumes/COYOTE/Developer/tibra/lib_managed/jars/org.osgi/org.osgi.core/org.osgi.core-4.3.1.jar:OSGI-OPT/bnd.bnd
[error] /Volumes/COYOTE/Developer/tibra/lib_managed/jars/org.osgi/org.osgi.compendium/org.osgi.compendium-4.3.1.jar:OSGI-OPT/bnd.bnd
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Volumes/COYOTE/Developer/tibra/lib_managed/bundles/com.google.guava/guava/guava-18.0.jar:com/google/common/base/Absent.class
[error] /Volumes/COYOTE/Developer/tibra/lib_managed/jars/org.apache.spark/spark-network-common_2.11/spark-network-common_2.11-1.5.1.jar:com/google/common/base/Absent.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Volumes/COYOTE/Developer/tibra/lib_managed/bundles/com.google.guava/guava/guava-18.0.jar:com/google/common/base/Function.class
[error] /Volumes/COYOTE/Developer/tibra/lib_managed/jars/org.apache.spark/spark-network-common_2.11/spark-network-common_2.11-1.5.1.jar:com/google/common/base/Function.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Volumes/COYOTE/Developer/tibra/lib_managed/bundles/com.google.guava/guava/guava-18.0.jar:com/google/common/base/Optional$1$1.class
[error] /Volumes/COYOTE/Developer/tibra/lib_managed/jars/org.apache.spark/spark-network-common_2.11/spark-network-common_2.11-1.5.1.jar:com/google/common/base/Optional$1$1.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Volumes/COYOTE/Developer/tibra/lib_managed/bundles/com.google.guava/guava/guava-18.0.jar:com/google/common/base/Optional$1.class
[error] /Volumes/COYOTE/Developer/tibra/lib_managed/jars/org.apache.spark/spark-network-common_2.11/spark-network-common_2.11-1.5.1.jar:com/google/common/base/Optional$1.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Volumes/COYOTE/Developer/tibra/lib_managed/bundles/com.google.guava/guava/guava-18.0.jar:com/google/common/base/Optional.class
[error] /Volumes/COYOTE/Developer/tibra/lib_managed/jars/org.apache.spark/spark-network-common_2.11/spark-network-common_2.11-1.5.1.jar:com/google/common/base/Optional.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Volumes/COYOTE/Developer/tibra/lib_managed/bundles/com.google.guava/guava/guava-18.0.jar:com/google/common/base/Present.class
[error] /Volumes/COYOTE/Developer/tibra/lib_managed/jars/org.apache.spark/spark-network-common_2.11/spark-network-common_2.11-1.5.1.jar:com/google/common/base/Present.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Volumes/COYOTE/Developer/tibra/lib_managed/bundles/com.google.guava/guava/guava-18.0.jar:com/google/common/base/Supplier.class
[error] /Volumes/COYOTE/Developer/tibra/lib_managed/jars/org.apache.spark/spark-network-common_2.11/spark-network-common_2.11-1.5.1.jar:com/google/common/base/Supplier.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Volumes/COYOTE/Developer/tibra/lib_managed/jars/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-yarn-common/hadoop-yarn-common-2.2.0.jar:org/apache/hadoop/yarn/factories/package-info.class
[error] /Volumes/COYOTE/Developer/tibra/lib_managed/jars/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-yarn-api/hadoop-yarn-api-2.2.0.jar:org/apache/hadoop/yarn/factories/package-info.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Volumes/COYOTE/Developer/tibra/lib_managed/jars/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-yarn-common/hadoop-yarn-common-2.2.0.jar:org/apache/hadoop/yarn/factory/providers/package-info.class
[error] /Volumes/COYOTE/Developer/tibra/lib_managed/jars/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-yarn-api/hadoop-yarn-api-2.2.0.jar:org/apache/hadoop/yarn/factory/providers/package-info.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Volumes/COYOTE/Developer/tibra/lib_managed/jars/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-yarn-common/hadoop-yarn-common-2.2.0.jar:org/apache/hadoop/yarn/util/package-info.class
[error] /Volumes/COYOTE/Developer/tibra/lib_managed/jars/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-yarn-api/hadoop-yarn-api-2.2.0.jar:org/apache/hadoop/yarn/util/package-info.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Volumes/COYOTE/Developer/tibra/lib_managed/jars/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11/spark-core_2.11-1.5.1.jar:org/apache/spark/unused/UnusedStubClass.class
[error] /Volumes/COYOTE/Developer/tibra/lib_managed/jars/org.apache.spark/spark-launcher_2.11/spark-launcher_2.11-1.5.1.jar:org/apache/spark/unused/UnusedStubClass.class
[error] /Volumes/COYOTE/Developer/tibra/lib_managed/jars/org.spark-project.spark/unused/unused-1.0.0.jar:org/apache/spark/unused/UnusedStubClass.class
[error] /Volumes/COYOTE/Developer/tibra/lib_managed/jars/org.apache.spark/spark-network-common_2.11/spark-network-common_2.11-1.5.1.jar:org/apache/spark/unused/UnusedStubClass.class
[error] /Volumes/COYOTE/Developer/tibra/lib_managed/jars/org.apache.spark/spark-network-shuffle_2.11/spark-network-shuffle_2.11-1.5.1.jar:org/apache/spark/unused/UnusedStubClass.class
[error] /Volumes/COYOTE/Developer/tibra/lib_managed/jars/org.apache.spark/spark-unsafe_2.11/spark-unsafe_2.11-1.5.1.jar:org/apache/spark/unused/UnusedStubClass.class
[error] /Volumes/COYOTE/Developer/tibra/lib_managed/jars/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.11/spark-sql_2.11-1.5.1.jar:org/apache/spark/unused/UnusedStubClass.class
[error] /Volumes/COYOTE/Developer/tibra/lib_managed/jars/org.apache.spark/spark-catalyst_2.11/spark-catalyst_2.11-1.5.1.jar:org/apache/spark/unused/UnusedStubClass.class
[error] /Volumes/COYOTE/Developer/tibra/lib_managed/jars/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming_2.11/spark-streaming_2.11-1.5.1.jar:org/apache/spark/unused/UnusedStubClass.class
[error] (core/*:assembly) deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/bryan/.ivy2/cache/org.osgi/org.osgi.core/jars/org.osgi.core-4.3.1.jar:OSGI-OPT/bnd.bnd
[error] /Users/bryan/.ivy2/cache/org.osgi/org.osgi.compendium/jars/org.osgi.compendium-4.3.1.jar:OSGI-OPT/bnd.bnd
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/bryan/.ivy2/cache/com.google.guava/guava/bundles/guava-18.0.jar:com/google/common/base/Absent.class
[error] /Users/bryan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.spark/spark-network-common_2.11/jars/spark-network-common_2.11-1.5.1.jar:com/google/common/base/Absent.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/bryan/.ivy2/cache/com.google.guava/guava/bundles/guava-18.0.jar:com/google/common/base/Function.class
[error] /Users/bryan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.spark/spark-network-common_2.11/jars/spark-network-common_2.11-1.5.1.jar:com/google/common/base/Function.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/bryan/.ivy2/cache/com.google.guava/guava/bundles/guava-18.0.jar:com/google/common/base/Optional$1$1.class
[error] /Users/bryan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.spark/spark-network-common_2.11/jars/spark-network-common_2.11-1.5.1.jar:com/google/common/base/Optional$1$1.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/bryan/.ivy2/cache/com.google.guava/guava/bundles/guava-18.0.jar:com/google/common/base/Optional$1.class
[error] /Users/bryan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.spark/spark-network-common_2.11/jars/spark-network-common_2.11-1.5.1.jar:com/google/common/base/Optional$1.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/bryan/.ivy2/cache/com.google.guava/guava/bundles/guava-18.0.jar:com/google/common/base/Optional.class
[error] /Users/bryan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.spark/spark-network-common_2.11/jars/spark-network-common_2.11-1.5.1.jar:com/google/common/base/Optional.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/bryan/.ivy2/cache/com.google.guava/guava/bundles/guava-18.0.jar:com/google/common/base/Present.class
[error] /Users/bryan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.spark/spark-network-common_2.11/jars/spark-network-common_2.11-1.5.1.jar:com/google/common/base/Present.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/bryan/.ivy2/cache/com.google.guava/guava/bundles/guava-18.0.jar:com/google/common/base/Supplier.class
[error] /Users/bryan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.spark/spark-network-common_2.11/jars/spark-network-common_2.11-1.5.1.jar:com/google/common/base/Supplier.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/bryan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-yarn-common/jars/hadoop-yarn-common-2.2.0.jar:org/apache/hadoop/yarn/factories/package-info.class
[error] /Users/bryan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-yarn-api/jars/hadoop-yarn-api-2.2.0.jar:org/apache/hadoop/yarn/factories/package-info.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/bryan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-yarn-common/jars/hadoop-yarn-common-2.2.0.jar:org/apache/hadoop/yarn/factory/providers/package-info.class
[error] /Users/bryan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-yarn-api/jars/hadoop-yarn-api-2.2.0.jar:org/apache/hadoop/yarn/factory/providers/package-info.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/bryan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-yarn-common/jars/hadoop-yarn-common-2.2.0.jar:org/apache/hadoop/yarn/util/package-info.class
[error] /Users/bryan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-yarn-api/jars/hadoop-yarn-api-2.2.0.jar:org/apache/hadoop/yarn/util/package-info.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/bryan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11/jars/spark-core_2.11-1.5.1.jar:org/apache/spark/unused/UnusedStubClass.class
[error] /Users/bryan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.spark/spark-launcher_2.11/jars/spark-launcher_2.11-1.5.1.jar:org/apache/spark/unused/UnusedStubClass.class
[error] /Users/bryan/.ivy2/cache/org.spark-project.spark/unused/jars/unused-1.0.0.jar:org/apache/spark/unused/UnusedStubClass.class
[error] /Users/bryan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.spark/spark-network-common_2.11/jars/spark-network-common_2.11-1.5.1.jar:org/apache/spark/unused/UnusedStubClass.class
[error] /Users/bryan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.spark/spark-network-shuffle_2.11/jars/spark-network-shuffle_2.11-1.5.1.jar:org/apache/spark/unused/UnusedStubClass.class
[error] /Users/bryan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.spark/spark-unsafe_2.11/jars/spark-unsafe_2.11-1.5.1.jar:org/apache/spark/unused/UnusedStubClass.class
[error] /Users/bryan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.11/jars/spark-sql_2.11-1.5.1.jar:org/apache/spark/unused/UnusedStubClass.class
[error] /Users/bryan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.spark/spark-catalyst_2.11/jars/spark-catalyst_2.11-1.5.1.jar:org/apache/spark/unused/UnusedStubClass.class
[error] /Users/bryan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming_2.11/jars/spark-streaming_2.11-1.5.1.jar:org/apache/spark/unused/UnusedStubClass.class
[error] (commons/*:assembly) deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/bryan/.ivy2/cache/org.osgi/org.osgi.core/jars/org.osgi.core-4.3.1.jar:OSGI-OPT/bnd.bnd
[error] /Users/bryan/.ivy2/cache/org.osgi/org.osgi.compendium/jars/org.osgi.compendium-4.3.1.jar:OSGI-OPT/bnd.bnd
```

I tried all the recommend solutions here with no luck.

[sbt-assembly: deduplication found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25144484/sbt-assembly-deduplication-found-error?rq=1)

[deduplicating commons-validator - sbt assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30574262/deduplicating-commons-validator-sbt-assembly)

[spark + sbt-assembly: "deduplicate: different file contents found in the following"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30446984/spark-sbt-assembly-deduplicate-different-file-contents-found-in-the-followi)

Comment: I had also the same issues since Spark 1.4.1 and I have tried all the recommended solutions, none of them worked. I had to switch to maven afterward.

Comment: @eliasah I figured out a way around this - still using SBT as maven is pretty much a no-go when we have a better tool around.  I ditched `sbt-assembly` as the same bug is occuring for many different libraries and the work arounds are questionable at best, which is (to me) indicative of problems with the projects future.  Use `sbt-native-packager`.  I would post it as an answer but in context that would just be a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

This is not exactly an answer to the problem, but it is a workaround.

*I hope this saves a few hundred man-hours.*

Use [`sbt-native-packager`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/) instead of `sbt-assembly`.

Add to `plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.0.0")
```

And in your `build.sbt`

```
enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)
enablePlugins(UniversalPlugin)
```

To build the files for multiple Scala versions use the +

```
+ universal:packageBin
```

The output will tell you where the file was created.

Unfortunately the generated jars are zipped.  It is not a fat jar.  (to generate a fat jar would require `sbt-assembly` which has the same issues)

To overcome this, I made a simple script (in SBT) that unzips the generated files and writes the jar paths to a file so I can easily build a Spark submit script.

```
packageBin in TxtFormat := {

    val zippedJar = "core-backend-1.0.zip"
    val basePath = target.value / "universal"

    // Unzip to folder of JARs
    IO.unzip(basePath / zippedJar, basePath)

    val fileMappings = (mappings in Universal).value
    val sparkScriptOut = basePath / s"${packageName.value}.txt"

    // append all mappings to the list
    fileMappings foreach {
        case (file, name) => IO.append(sparkScriptOut, s"core-backend-1.0/$name${IO.Newline}")
    }
    sparkScriptOut
}
```

After building the zip, use this to execute the task:

```
+ txtFormat:packageBin
```

Answer (score 1):

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
case PathList("org", "apache", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
case PathList("com", "google", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
case x =>
    val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
    oldStrategy(x)
}
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Spark dependencies should be provided by the cluster, add the "Provided":

```
val Spark =  Seq(
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % Provided,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % Provided,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion % Provided
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but none of the solutions given so far handle the case I encountered.

It appears there are cases where a jar that is not "provided" has dependencies on jars that are.  If the transitive dependencies pull in jars with conflicting content, you can see this same error.  In certain cases, adding those jars as dependencies marked "provided" has not resolved the conflicts between them when the assembly is being built.  The only solution I have found is to explicitly exclude them from the assembly as follows.

```
assemblyExcludedJars in assembly := {
    val cp = (fullClasspath in assembly).value
    cp filter { el =>
        (el.data.getName == "unused-1.0.0.jar") ||
        (el.data.getName == "spark-tags_2.11-2.1.0.jar")  
    }
}
```